# How to extraxt the values from XML and if I do that I'm getting error 'element-start tag is not well formed'

Tags: sql, xml, soap, oracle11g

As I'm new to this concept, I have gone through the all the resources from google but not found how to extract the values.

Below is my xml stranded format which the client will send the xml as a request.

By extracting the values I have to pass that to procedure as parameters.

here is the sql query I'm using for extract values from XML...

```
SELECT
   XMLTYPE(l_request).EXTRACT('//txtBranchCode/text()').getStringVal()
FROM
   dual ;
```

and XML is:

```
l_request:='<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soap:Body>
            <ns2:fundTransferAccountToMobile xmlns:ns2="http://deploy.fasyl.xnett.com/">
            <txtUserId>SUCHITH</txtUserId>
            <txtPassword>pass</txtPassword>
            <txtBankName>GCB</txtBankName>
            <txtBranchCode>A00</txtBranchCode>
            <txtAccountNumber>A001041111220100042</txtAccountNumber>
            <txtBFName>test</txtBFName>
            <txtBLName>test</txtBLName>
            <txtAmount>15.0</txtAmount>
            <txtCurrency>GHS</txtCurrency>
            <txtRefID>1</txtRefID>
            <mydate>2016-07-1308:01:48.014</mydate>
            <txtCountryCode>233</txtCountryCode>
            <txtAuthNum>9743699236</txtAuthNum>
            <txtExternal1>null</txtExternal1>
            <txtExternal2>null</txtExternal2>
            </ns2:fundTransferAccountToMobile>
            </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>';
```

Say for exp I have to extract the value for txtBranchCode, I'm using the above query and I'm getting the error  "element-start tag is not well formed"...

Please kindly assist me on this...

Comment: Please correctly tag with the DBMS you are using (vendor and version). The tag "sql" is not enough...

Comment: @ Shnugo I have edited the tags as you have assisted..

Comment: @Shnugo Vender is Airtel and Version is 11g

Comment: From the `11g` I assume this is oracle? Most important is to specify the actual sql dialect. Querying XML is highly product specific...

Comment: @Shnugo yes its Oracle. I came to know where the error occurred. in XML after 'soap:Envelope' they should have to give single space. This works for me now. still facing the another issue. In the same XML I have to extract 'fundTransferAccountToMobile'. Based on this I have to call the procedure. Actually 'fundTransferAccountToMobile' is action code. May I get query for this plz?

Comment: Don't know exactly... I'm not on Oracle and have no test environment... However: `fundTransferAccountToMobile` does not carry data, it's just the nest of several sub-elements... Your problem might be connected to the namespace. Read about declaring a namespace or use a wildcard, something like `*:fundTransferAccountToMobile`.

Comment: @Shnugo Okay fine but I got result by using 'instr' function in oracle. Thank you for your assist. Thank you soo much.